# What is proper way to update serbanghita-mobile-detect

Tags: php, mobile, detect

I have most recent version of serbanghita-mobile-detect ([serbanghita](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect)).

However, I have a Asus PadFone2 tablet/phone device which is not being handled correctly by it:

```
Mozilla/5.0 
(Linux; U; Android 4.1.1; en-gb; PadFone 2 Build/JRO03L) 
AppleWebKit/534.30  
(KHTML, like Gecko) 
Version/4.0 Safari/534.30
```

So I would like to manually update it for this device.

Comment: Open a ticket on https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/issues

Comment: Why don't they just include Mobile in the UA – That's the traditional way to deal with this. Stupid Asus :(

Comment: Stijn ... I am new to github ... I was unaware that they had a 'issues' forum ... so I signed up and submitted my question.

Comment: @RichBradshaw ... this particular UA is for the PadFone2's tablet state (I did not check to see if the phone has the same ua)

Comment: Ah, it might be that the phone will be detected, in which case that's deliberate behaviour. It's unusual to treat a tablet as a 'mobile' device in many occasions. What are you actually trying to do hear?

Answer (score 0):

Stijn responded correct. I look at the issues, do some research and then update the library after all the UnitTests pass.

If you don't know how to add an issue, just send me the feedback via http://demo.mobiledetect.net